# Xcode not finding directory within resources group

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Xcode will not seem to recognize a particular directory of files in the Resources group. This is how I'm retrieving the folder:

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
2011-03-06 17:52:47.660 [*removed*][36648:207] Could not locate any tiles at /Users/james/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/909785DD-B3E8-41CB-A3D9-C19D1826C448/[*removed*].app/Tiles
```

I checked, and sure enough that directory does not exist. But it does exist in the project directory.

I have done the following:

- Deleted the app off of the simulator
- Deleted the "Tiles" folder from the actual app directory and from within the Resources group in Xcode
- Cleaned all targets
- Dragged the "Tiles" folder from another location directly into the "Resources" group in Xcode and told it to copy into the directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File groups in XCode don't necessarily translate to folders inside your compiled application bundle.

Try using this alternate method for accessing your application resources:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Note that you don't have to specify where your `MyFile.txt` file actually is -- as long as it exists in your project as a resource, it will be found.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the folder organization actually translates over into the bundle? Looks like the files just spill out into the bundle with no structure.

Comment: When you add a directory to your project, select *Create Folder References for any added folders*.